# Adding a Host on CloudStack development environment

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I set a CloudStack development environment on Ubuntu 12.04 according to [[this]](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/Setting+up+CloudStack+Development+Environment+on+Linux)

It works well, but I can't add a host through the management server UI.
I tested on released binary one, It could add the hosts. (Hypervisor: KVM)

I confirmed the log on terminal while the management server is running, It just said "unable to add host".

How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself!

That's because of version. My CloudStack management server source version from GitHub was 4.2.0. But agent version was 4.1.0. So I changed source version 4.1.0. And, It was working well.

Answer (score 0):

Send this question to the [Apache CloudStack developer mailing list](http://cloudstack.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).

Be prepared to provide a copy of the command you used to start the management server, the exact text from 10 lines before and 10 lines after the "unable to add host" message, and a copy of any exceptions that occured before this message.